# Deformations of null-vectors of an integral unimodular lattice

Tags: lattices

Is there an $SO(n,n)$ transformation that makes the Euclidean norm-squared of all the null vectors of the $(n,n)$ hypercubic lattice strictly greater than 4?

Example: Let $\Lambda_{\rm sL}$ denote the (23-dimensional) shorter Leech lattice.
The minimal norm-squared of any vector is 3. Therefore, all null vectors of the lattice $\Lambda_{\rm sL} \oplus \Lambda_{\rm sL}$ have Euclidean norm-squared at least 6. 
Since all odd integral unimodular lattices are equivalent up to an $SO(n,n)$, then the lattice $\Lambda_{\rm sL} \oplus \Lambda_{\rm sL}$ is related to the 46-dimensional hypercubic lattice.

Is there an example with $n < 23$?

Comment: From Minkowski's Convex Body theorem it follows that a lattice can have Eucliean norm-squared of 4 or greater only in dimensions 12 or higher. So there is at least a lower bound for $n$.